# new byte[]{0} in Objective C

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, nsstream

I'm trying to port the following Java code to Objective C.

```
myByteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(myCfA.length() + 1);
myByteBuffer.write(myCfA.getBytes());
myByteBuffer.write(new byte[]{0});
myWriter.write(myByteBuffer.toByteArray());
myWriter.flush();
```

It's relevant Objective-C code

```
NSInteger strLength = self.myCfA.length;
NSMutableString *response  = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:strLength];
[response appendString:self.myCfA];
[response appendString:@"0"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSInteger bytesCount = [self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

Is my approach of taking NSMutableString and then converting into NSData and getting bytes a correct approach? Also for new byte[]{0} I'm directly appending 0 as string. Please correct me if I'm going wrong. There is an issue here which I'm unable to trace out.

Thanks
Sudheer

Answer (score 0):

self.myCfA is a string and you can directly convert that to NSData. So the code given below will give you the same result.

```
NSData *data = [self.myCfA dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSInteger bytesCount = [self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

**Update:** To append byte to the existing data.

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[self.myCfA dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[data appendBytes:[@"\0" UTF8String] length:1];
NSInteger bytesCount = [self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

Comment: ok but what about new byte[]{0} in ObjectiveC. How do we port it to give bytes or NSData?

Comment: Why do you need the terminal null character?  (But if you need it I think it would be `@"\0"`.)

Comment: the line [data appendBytes:0x00 length:1]; is resulting in a crash :(

Comment: I think the expected array should be terminated with null char.

Comment: @AugustinePA - Shouldn't be any need to terminate with a null -- the NSData has an explicit length.